# HTML5: Display images dropped in dropzone in img tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently designing a small webpage that let's you upload png files to a ftp server using a dropzone in HTML5. When a user does drop an valid image into the dropzone, I would like to present the image within a `<img ... />` tag. I got the javascript code for the dropzone, and I tried to change the src attribute by using `MYPICTUREID.src = file.name;`. This does not work since file.name brings you just the name, not the entire path. From what I read is that you can't obtain the path to the local file on the users device due to safety restrictions. What would be the best way to create a preview for a user?

[image: Picture of the planed webpage]

Comment: If you're interested, http://dropzonejs.com already does this really nicely

Comment: This is indeed very nice, but I have a very specific layout that I'm forced to use on this page, and it would be very time consuming to configure it the right way. But this seems to be a very interesting project non the less.

Answer (score 2):

I found a simple solution to the problem:

using `_URL.createObjectURL(file)` you can generate pathes for the uploaded files.

This are really just two lines:

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
_URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FileReader.readAsDataURL` to accomplish this.

```js
var dropbox = document.getElementById("dropbox");
dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragenter, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragover, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);

function dragenter(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function drop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var dt = e.dataTransfer,
      file = dt.files[0],
      img = document.createElement('img'),
      reader = new FileReader();
  
  dropbox.appendChild(img);

  reader.onload = function(e) {
    img.src = e.target.result;
  };
  
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```css
#dropbox {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropbox"></div>
```