# Dropzone.js create <img> tag based on server response

Tags: javascript, dropzone

I have a question, similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38529968/html5-display-images-dropped-in-dropzone-in-img-tag) but instead of adding the **uploaded** file to the img tag, I wish to add the server's response to an image tag.  The server responds with:

```
from flask import send_file
return send_file(data, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

The actual response can be verified in the network tab of firefox:

[image: sample image response]

I have created an event handler to try and get this to the img tag:

```
myDropzone.on('success', function (file, response) {

  var img = document.createElement('img');  
  var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  img.src=_URL.createObjectURL(response);

  var ul = document.getElementById('list' );
  li = document.createElement('li') 
  li.appendChild(img)
  ul.appendChild(li);
});
```

However this gives me the following error at the console:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads of URL.createObjectURL.
```

I suspect I need to pass this something different from `response`, but my understaning (?) is `response` is the RAW data (and the same as `file` in the linked example)

Another approach I had to this was:

```
myDropzone.on('success', function (file, response) {

  var img = document.createElement('img');  
  var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

  const blob = new Blob([response]);    
  //img.src=_URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    var base64data = reader.result;
    img.src=base64data;

    var ul = document.getElementById('list' );
    li = document.createElement('li') 
    li.appendChild(img)
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
});
```

This got me closer to the expected result, where an img tag is loaded in the DOM like:

```
<img src="data:application/octet-stream;base64,77+977+977+977+9ABB.....=" />
```

However this appears to have the incorrect MIMEtype, and the image doesn't actually load.  What's the correct way to approach this?  I realise I should probably have the server respond with a URL to a separate endpoint, then make `src` that URL however I'm curious on how to render it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const blob = new Blob([response]);
img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunatey this seems to make the `src` tag = `blob:http://localhost:5000/d22399kc-8200-594f-aedc-053bc66e5431` which puzzles me completely.